# Js Change input color

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap

Using bootstrap, I need to change, if there's an error like this, to show the inputfield as red. with the placeholder..THe place holder is ready but I wanna mark the field as red (using bootstrap)..

This is the JS

```
if (data['valid'] != "true") {
     if(data['path_error']) {
         oRow.children('#path_td').attr( 'data-container', 'body')
                                  .attr( 'data-toggle', 'popover')
                                  .attr( 'data-placement', 'top')
                                  .attr( 'data-content', data['path_error'])
                                  .attr( 'data-class', 'bg-danger')
                                  .popover('show');
     }
```

EDIT:
this is the HTML

```
<td id="path_td"><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="path"
                       value="<?= $oRoute->getPath(); ?>"/></td>
```

Comment: what is "oRow" in your example? i see you are using the children() method - are you using JQuery?

Comment: var oRow = $(this).closest('tr');

Comment: please post JS around your if statement.

Comment: btw, if the TD has an ID, you don't need children(). Just $("#path_td").attr(...

Comment: This is the file http://pastebin.com/N7Q77gZR

Comment: btw, you shouldn't declare a function with the "new" keyword. Just var route = function(){...}

Comment: have you checked if the class is applied to the TD?

Comment: Yes..If not I wouldn't see the place holder...<the input field isn't marking as red :(

Comment: if the class is applied to the right object, then there isn't a CSS class named 'bg-danger'. Have you added the bootstrap CSS?

Comment: or maybe bg-danger isn't a 'valid' class for inputs. check the bootstrap API: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

Comment: <div class="form-group has-error">
  <label class="control-label" for="inputError1">Input with error</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputError1">
This is the error. So how do I add the class control-label for inputError in js?

Comment: $('#path_td').parent().addClass('someClass'), perhaps? if your HTML has that layout, that is.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to change the data-class, but rather class itself. Assuming you are using JQuery (you are using closest() and children() methods)

```
$('#path_td')
  .addClass('bg-danger')
  .attr( 'data-container', 'body')
  .attr( 'data-toggle', 'popover')
  .attr( 'data-placement', 'top')
  .attr( 'data-content', data['path_error'])
  .popover('show');
```

Comment: Where should I add it?
As you can see, the attribute 'data-class', 'bg-danger' is implemented, but I don't see it....

Comment: @GianlucaBelardinelli i clarified my answer for you.

Comment: so I shouldn't consider the part above right?
If I copy the code below, still nothing..I see the popover but it doesn't change color...

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:

```
function showError(oRow, where, what) {
    oRow.find(where).attr( 'data-container', 'body').attr( 'data-toggle', 'popover').attr( 'data-placement', 'top').attr( 'data-content', what).attr( 'data-class', 'bg-danger').popover('show');
    oRow.find( where).addClass('has-error');

 var jsonCallback = function(oRow) {
        return function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            if (data['valid'] != "true") {
                if(data['path_error']) {
                    showError(oRow, '#path_td', data['path_error']);
                }
```